# iOS 7 uinavigationbar appearance issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have a very strange bug going on that I can't seem to figure out. Throughout my app in iOS 7 the navigation bar looks exactly how I want it to (gradient background, sits below the status bar). But, when a video or MFMailComposeViewController is presented modally, then subsequently dismissed, the navigationbar for that view stack reverts back to the iOS 7 way of sitting behind the status bar, and there is an extra bar underneath. In case that explanation didn't make any sense, here is a picture of the navigation bar before (top) and after (bottom) a video is presented/dismissed:

[Navigation Bar Image](http://oi43.tinypic.com/167qvk1.jpg)

I have set the UIAppearance for the navigation bar both app-wide as well as trying to re-set it in viewWillAppear to no avail. I have also set edgesForExtendedLayout to UIRectEdgeNone, set the statusBarStyle to Black Opaque in the info.plist, and set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO in the info.plist.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

-Stephen

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that calling `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];` in your view controller's `viewWillAppear` method will solve your problem.  But you probably solved it long ago since I just now noticed the date of your question :)

I found that this didn't always solve the problem in all cases.  What does seem to solve it for the cases I'm seeing is:

add `[self.view setNeedsLayout];` in `viewWillAppear:` method of your view controller.  Putting it in `viewDidAppear:` didn't work (not sure why - too late?).